# Using printf to display the result of a method with 16 places

Tags: java

My code display the output using `println` but when I use `printf`, I am getting an error at execution. The end result is to have an output like this:

```
Enter an integer: 5

The 16 bits are 0000000000000101
```

Where can I make a change that will give the above result and no errors? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class decimalToBits{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //initiate variables
        int integer;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt user to input short integer
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");

        integer = input.nextInt();

        //calculate integer into 16 bits

        //display results
        System.out.printf("The bits for decimal input of %d are %d", integer, deciamalToInt(integer));

    }

        //convert short integer into 16 bit integer
        public static String decimalToInt(int integer){
            String bits = "";

            while (integer != 0){
                int bitsValue = integer % 2;
                bits = toBitsChar(bitsValue) + bits;
                integer = integer / 2;
            }

        return bits;

        }

        //Convert an integer to a single 16 bit digit
        public static char toBitsChar(int bitsValue){
            if (bitsValue > 0)
                return (char)('1'); //display 1 if value is greater than 0
            else 
                return (char)('0'); //display 0 if value is 0
        }
}
```

Get the following error:

```
Enter an integer: 
5
Exception in thread "main" The bits for decimal input of 5 are java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at decimalToBits.main(decimalToBits.java:22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
.."The bits for decimal input of %d are %d", integer, decimalToInt(integer));
                                      ↑
```

You are using `%d` to print String. Use `%s` instead.

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Comment: This works and thank you. The output is 101 with an input of 5. How do I get it to output 000000000000101?

Answer (score 0):

DecimalToInt should be named IntegerToBitString. It returns a string, so the correct format modifier is %s, not %d wich expects an integer. Java and C are widely compatible in the modifiers, so google for "printf format" should lead you to tables of modifiers and options.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of work to achieve a 16 bit binay representation. As simple as it is , I'd do something like this:

```
int x = 5;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x10000 | x).substring(1));
```

This will print **0000000000000101** in your console.

Comment: Just getting started, this looks really nice but haven't covered it yet in class. Didn't want to put that in the code if I couldn't explain it. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

Use %s instead of %d in "System.out.printf(...)".